# Take a line after a mentioned line

Tags: regex, tcl

Input:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
my_data1 12 23 34
my_data2 10 23 4
my_data3 1 2 34
my_data4 12 3 3
```

and so on...

Output:

```
my_data1 12 23 34
```

I want my Tcl code to look for Line 1 expression ie starting with a `@` (`^@`) and print **only** the next line.

Comment: Please add the code that you are using to read the file. Is the input a list or file ?

Comment: You've done most of the work by specifying it :-) See [How do I read and write files in Tcl](http://wiki.tcl.tk/367) as well as [string](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm) and [puts](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/puts.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to read all the data in and use a suitable `lsearch`.

```
set f [open $filename]
set lines [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

set matched [lsearch -all -regexp $lines {^@}]

foreach idx $matched {
    puts [lindex $lines [expr {$idx + 1}]]
}
```

That's assuming you want all the lines after a line starting with `@`. To get just the first:

```
set idx [lsearch -regexp $lines {^@}]
if {$idx >= 0} {
    puts [lindex $lines [expr {$idx + 1}]]
}
```

That is, no `-all` and no looping over the results, and instead checking that we didn't get `-1` (documented indicator of no-match).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to do what you need, by reading the file line-by-line.

```
 set fp [open "somefile" r]
 set file_data [read $fp]
 close $fp

 set read_next 0
 #  Process data
 foreach line [split $file_data "\n"] {
      if {[string index $line 0] == "-"} {
          set read_next 1
          continue
      }
      if {$read_next == 1} {
          puts $line
      }
      set read_next 0
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions are fine, but maybe somewhat too complicated. To provide some contrast:

```
while {![eof $in]} { if {[regexp {^@} [gets $in]]} { puts [gets $in] ; break } }
```

this assumes the value of `in` is a channel open for reading (it could be `stdin`, or an opened file).

The logic behind it is: read a line; if it matches, read one more line and print that, then quit. Repeat until input is exhausted.

ETA: in case the one-liner is hard to parse visually, here's the same thing on more lines:

```
while {![eof $in]} {
    if {[regexp {^@} [gets $in]]} {
        puts [gets $in]
        break
    }
}
```

Writing like this makes the structure much more clear, but this solution is basically a one-liner, really.

Comment: I usually avoid writing one-liners in order to keep code as clear as possible; code-golf belongs elsewhere. :-)